# how to make a React-Query with React-Hook-Form Autosave

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, react-query

I am trying to make a form with React-Hook-Form and React-Query that autosaves whenever the user changes any of the fields (debounced). I am getting close, but it creates an infinite loop when I mutate. Here is what I have:

```
"@tanstack/react-query": "^4.2.3",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.34.2",
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { useMutation, useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { yupResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/yup'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import debounce from 'just-debounce-it'

type NameType = {
    id: number
    firstName: string
    lastName: string
}

const schemaValidation = Yup.object().shape({
    id: Yup.number().required('Required'),
    firstName: Yup.string().required('Required'),
    lastName: Yup.string()
        .min(2, 'Must be greater than 1 character')
        .max(50, 'Must be less than 50 characters')
})

const getMockData = async () => {
    const name: NameType = {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe'
    }
    return await Promise.resolve(name)
}

const saveChangeToDatabase = async (args: NameType) => {
    console.count('payload for patch:' + JSON.stringify(args))
    return await Promise.resolve(args)
}

const NameForm = () => {
    const queryResult = useQuery(['user'], getMockData)
    const mutationResult = useMutation(saveChangeToDatabase, {
        onSuccess: (nameToSave: NameType) => {
            console.count('success mutating: ' + JSON.stringify(nameToSave))
        }
    })

    const {
        register,
        reset,
        watch,
        formState: { isValid, isDirty, errors }
    } = useForm<NameType>({
        mode: 'all',
        criteriaMode: 'all',
        resolver: yupResolver(schemaValidation)
    })
    const fieldData = watch()

    const handleDebouncedChange = debounce((data: NameType) => {
        mutationResult.mutateAsync(data)
    }, 500)

    React.useEffect(() => {
        reset(queryResult.data)
    }, [queryResult.data])

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (isValid && isDirty) {
            handleDebouncedChange(fieldData)
        }
    }, [fieldData, isValid, isDirty])

    if (queryResult.isLoading) {
        return <h2>Loading...</h2>
    }

    return (
        <div
            style={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                margin: 'auto',
                width: 300
            }}>
            <input {...register('firstName')} placeholder='First name' />
            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errors && errors?.firstName?.message}</div>
            <input {...register('lastName')} placeholder='Last name' />
            <div style={{ color: 'red' }}>{errors && errors?.lastName?.message}</div>
            {'Field data: ' + JSON.stringify(fieldData)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default NameForm
```

I also made a create-react-app reproduction of this here. You can clone the repo, run npm i , npm start, and you will see the problem when you change the form. This is the only page you need to look at:

```
https://github.com/k-38/react-query_react-hook-form_autosave/blob/main/src/NameForm.tsx
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you

UPDATE: thanks so much for the answer. I took your answer and abstracted away a lot of the debounce/callback logic in a custom hook (not typed yet):

```
import React from 'react'
import debounce from 'just-debounce-it'

export function useDebouncedAutoSave({
    mutationResult,
    validationSchema,
    getValues,
    reset,
    queryResult
}: {
    mutationResult: any
    validationSchema: any
    getValues: any
    reset: any
    queryResult: any
}) {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        reset(queryResult.data)
    }, [queryResult.data])

    const handleDebouncedChange = React.useMemo(
        () =>
            debounce((data: any) => {
                mutationResult.mutateAsync(data)
            }, 500),
        [mutationResult.mutateAsync]
    )

    const onChange = async () => {
        try {
            const values = getValues()
            const validated = await validationSchema.validate(values)
            if (!validated) return
            handleDebouncedChange(validated)
        } catch (e) {}
    }

    return {
        onChange
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the infinite loop in functional component with `useEffect` is often due to dependencies values mutated on every "loop cycle".

In the [documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch) we can read:

> watch result is optimised for render phase instead of useEffect's deps, to detect value update you may want to use an external custom hook for value comparison.

I suspect (didn't had time to look at the code) that `watch` return value is created on every render. Then `fieldData` on every render is a reference to a new object.

Most of the time, I rely on `onChange` or `onBlur` form events.

```js
function Form() {
  const onChangeHandler = () => { /* ... */ };
  return <form onChange={onChangeHandler}>
   {/* ... */}
  </form>
}
```

And then I use `useForm().getValues` function to retrieve the current form values, but you need to use you schema validation to trigger the "autosave" function when its valid.

Another solution (maybe a simpler solution): would be to use a custom hook that compare the values deeply. You can take a look at `useDeepCompareEffect` from [react-use](https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useDeepCompareEffect.md) for this.

There is another bug in your code with the debounce function: using
`const debouncedFunction = debounce(myFunction, 500)` will not work. A "debounced" function is memoized. As we are in a render function (functional component), the memoized function will be created on every render, so it will be called without respect to the threshold that you set.

You need to use `React.useMemo` for this:

```js
  const { mutateAsync } = mutationResult;
  const handleDebouncedChange = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      debounce((data: NameType) => {
        mutateAsync(data);
      }, 500),
    [mutateAsync]
  );
```

A fully working version [available here as codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mcclintock-wd0djb?file=/src/NameForm.tsx:0-2589) would be:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useMutation, useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import debounce from "just-debounce-it";

type NameType = {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
};

const schemaValidation = Yup.object().shape({
  id: Yup.number().required("Required"),
  firstName: Yup.string().required("Required"),
  lastName: Yup.string()
    .required()
    .min(2, "Must be greater than 1 character")
    .max(50, "Must be less than 30 characters")
});

const getMockData = async () => {
  const name: NameType = {
    id: 1,
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
  };
  return await Promise.resolve(name);
};

const saveChangeToDatabase = async (args: NameType) => {
  console.count("payload for patch:" + JSON.stringify(args));
  return await Promise.resolve(args);
};

const NameForm = () => {
  const queryResult = useQuery(["user"], getMockData);
  const mutationResult = useMutation(saveChangeToDatabase, {
    onSuccess: (nameToSave: NameType) => {
      console.count("success mutating: " + JSON.stringify(nameToSave));
    }
  });

  const { register, reset, watch, getValues, formState } = useForm<NameType>({
    mode: "all",
    criteriaMode: "all",
    resolver: yupResolver(schemaValidation)
  });
  const { errors } = formState;
  const fieldData = watch();

  const { mutateAsync } = mutationResult;
  const handleDebouncedChange = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      debounce((data: NameType) => {
        mutateAsync(data);
      }, 500),
    [mutateAsync]
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    reset(queryResult.data);
  }, [queryResult.data]);

  const onChange = async () => {
    const data = getValues();
    try {
      console.log(formState);
      const validated = await schemaValidation.validate(data);
      handleDebouncedChange(validated);
    } catch (e) {}
  };

  if (queryResult.isLoading) {
    return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
  }

  return (
    <form
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        margin: "auto",
        width: 300
      }}
      onChange={onChange}
    >
      <input {...register("firstName")} placeholder="First name" />
      <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors && errors?.firstName?.message}</div>
      <input {...register("lastName")} placeholder="Last name" />
      <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{errors && errors?.lastName?.message}</div>
      {"Field data: " + JSON.stringify(fieldData)}
    </form>
  );
};

export default NameForm;
```